# How to manage RouteConfig in subprojects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am quite new in ASP.NET MVC.
I have a solution with different ASP.NET MVC projects and one of them is the main project.
If I define url patterns under RouteConfig file of each project (for each project it's own patterns), when I start the main project, urls does not works, but if I define url patterns in RouteConfig file of main project everything works fine.

I would like to know what is the best practice about this topic.

I think it has sense to define url patterns under RouteConfig of the specific project, but probably I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're talking about here. Each project has its own RouteConfig and it's own routes. They don't share routes and they aren't bound by the routes in other projects. When you publish each project to IIS, you will of course have to determine where it will be published to (it's own domain or subdomain), or a virtual directory, in which case, all your routes for that particular project would then be prefixed with the virtual directory path. You can't deploy multiple projects to the same location, so there's no chance of collision in the routes.